# How to open Preview with no documents

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, preview.app

I am using Preview on Mountain Lion (10.8.2). I opened a PDF in Preview and searched in it. Now whenever I open anything in Preview, it opens the PDF and the search always shows spinning on the original PDF. It hangs and I have to force close it.

Can I clear the files Preview has open with in a plist or from Terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> while launching an application will prevent it from reopening the documents that were active while the application was closed the last time.

Comment: Actually it's shift (not option and command). And it doesn't work if the application is opened from Spotlight, but it can be opened from the Dock, Finder, or Launchpad.